# ViewDidLoad Method is called again

Tags: ios, xcode, viewdidload

I have two View Controller. In the first I do some stuff and then I can push the second View Controller by clicking a button (the button connected with the other ViewController in the storyboard). There I can do some settings and so on. I get back to the first View Controller with the button "Done". But then the ViewDidLoad method is called again and all the "stuff" (text in textfields, ...) is gone.

I hope you guys understand my problem.

Why? And how can I disable this?

Comment: Please post the code showing how you are moving to second view controller.

Comment: I do this in the storyboard... rigth click on button->drag it to the second ViewController->Style:Modal

Answer (score 1):

How are you going back to the first view controller from the second one? I think your problem is you're re-instantiating the first view controller when the user hits "Done".

Instead, you should be using either "popViewControllerAnimated" or "dismissViewControllerAnimated" to go back to the first view controller.

e.g: (one of these 2 should work):

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I don't have a navigationController. In the storyboard I drag it with a right click on the button "Done" to the first ViewController.

Comment: +1: I agree, it sounds like he isn't popping/dismissing the view controller appropriately but is instead creating a new instance of it, which would indeed call `viewDidLoad:` "again" (it's a new instance after all)

Comment: ohh... nice. I just tested it with "[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];" and it worked. But now the problem is, if I add text in a textfield in the second ViewController, than go back to the first, then again in the second one, the text is gone...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `firstViewController` is unLoaded because of  receiving memory warning. So when it opened again, it calls `ViewDidLoad`